# Android 4.0 JSON fail

Tags: android, httpclient

I'm trying to get data from the web page with JSON format using HTTPCLient in Android 4.0 or above. The thing is that httpclient was successful to get the data with the link "http://extjs.org.cn/extjs/examples/grid/survey.html", but it was fail with the page i created "http://192.168.x.xxx:8888/xampp/jsonTest.php?type=1" and the JSON page output just like:

> {"Network":"Good"}

Does anyone know what the problem is? If not, is there another way to read JSON with my own pages.

Here is the code i wrote.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public EditText edit;

    public String readJSONFeed(String URL) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("JSON", "Failed to download file");
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    private class ReadJSONFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            return readJSONFeed(urls[0]);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
                Log.i("JSON", "Number of surveys in feed: " + jsonArray.length());
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), jsonObject.getString("Network"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    edit.setText("Check :" + jsonObject.getString("Network"));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        edit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.result1);
        new ReadJSONFeedTask().execute("http://192.168.x.xxx:8888/xampp/jsonTest.php?type=1");
        //new ReadJSONFeedTask().execute("http://extjs.org.cn/extjs/examples/grid/survey.html");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }    
}
```

ps. I done the Internet Access permission

Comment: Do you mean when you try to get the data from your own page you get {"Network":"Good"}, or you get an error?

Comment: The first URL returns a JSON array, the example JSON from your page is a JSON object that you're trying to parse as an array.

Comment: It was read the data {"Network":"Good"} only. No error and it was showing empty.